# Gitlab/Bitbucket - Block access for admin in a specific project

Tags: git, gitlab, bitbucket

Let's say I have a (really) private project that I do not want do share with anyone, including Gitlab/Bitbucket ("general", "owner") admins.

No one except me or a list of pre-defined persons can clone the repo.

The owner/admin may see that the repo exists, but how can I prevent them from cloning the source code?

Comment: I don't think that is possible. Even if you could "block" (whatever that means) the admin from cloning your source - it's the admin, so they will be able to "unblock" themselves. And chances are the admin has access to the machine running the Gitlab/Bitbucket instance, so they would have access to the (bare) repository anyway. I compare this to disallowing root on a UNIX(-like) machine to access a specific directory. It's impossible (correct me if I'm wrong please).

Comment: I think your argument closed the question...

Comment: I might be wrong, it's just an assumption (that's why I did not answer the question) - but disallowing admin or root to access a normal user's repository would undermine the meaning of an admin..

Comment: I'd suggest not putting the repo anywhere except the machines you trust.

Comment: Personal repositories sound like the closest to what you are asking for https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/creating-personal-repositories-776639832.html but still the server admin will be able to get access if they really want to get to the repo. You would probably have the host the Bitbucket instance yourself.